How to access a local variable from outside the function where it is declared?
How would I get the val selectedCountry which I believe is local to that function available to use in other functions or is there a way I can get what the current selected value of the spinner is?
I tried to treat it like Pyhton and Java where I would call the funtion and it would return that value but that did not work.
class MainActivity : ComponentActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(currencyconvertermain)
        val ConvertCurrency = findViewById<Button>(R.id.convertcurrency)
        val CurrencyOutput = findViewById<TextView>(R.id.currencyoutput)
        val CurrencyInput = findViewById<EditText>(R.id.currencyinput)
        val CountrySelect = findViewById<Spinner>(R.id.CountrySelect)
        val CountryImage = findViewById<ImageView>(R.id.CurrencyFlag)
        val CountrySelectAdapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this, R.array.dropdown_items, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item,)
        CountrySelect.adapter = CountrySelectAdapter

        CountrySelect.onItemSelectedListener = object : AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener {
            override fun onItemSelected(
                parentView: AdapterView<*>,
                selectedItemView: View?,
                position: Int,
                id: Long,
            ) {
                val selectedCountry = parentView.getItemAtPosition(position).toString()
                if (selectedCountry == "Japan") {
                    CountryImage.setImageResource(R.drawable.japan)
                }
                if (selectedCountry == "Phillipenes") {
                    CountryImage.setImageResource(R.drawable.philippines)
                }
                if (selectedCountry == "Nepal") {
                    CountryImage.setImageResource(R.drawable.nepal)
                }
                if (selectedCountry == "Vietnam") {
                    CountryImage.setImageResource(R.drawable.vietnam)
                }
                if (selectedCountry == "Taiwan") {
                    CountryImage.setImageResource(R.drawable.taiwan)
                }
            }

            override fun onNothingSelected(parentView: AdapterView<*>) {}
        }
    }
}


I don't know Kotlin, but in almost all programming language you can't access local variables from outside its scope.

Kotlin has a return statement, just like Python does.

Listeners presumably run asynchronously. So you can't return a value from them, since there's nothing to receive that returned value. You can set a global variable.

Would you be able to provide an example?

I assume this is an Android application (perhaps you should add a relevant tag). I have no experience of Android development, but perhaps you can move the val selectedCountry to a lateinit var selectedCountry outside of the function; then you will be able to see it outside of the function. Also, consider using when (selectedCountry) { "Japan" -> ... } instead of all those ifs.
